# virsh preboot script

Tags: virtual-machine, kvm, libvirt, virsh, pci-passthrough

I am running a virtual machine that requires vfio access to a PCI card. Using [this](https://github.com/andre-richter/vfio-pci-bind) script I am able to successfully bind the PCI device and its iommu group to vfio-pci, which then lets me boot up the VM:

1. `./vfio-pci-bind.sh 0000:03:00.0`
2. `virsh start myvm`

I want to do this automatically instead of having to manually bind to vfio-pci every time. Is there some sort of preflight/preboot script I can make virsh run before it attempts to boot a vm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [libvirt hook](https://www.libvirt.org/hooks.html) to run arbitrary programs when a VM or network is started or stopped.

For instance, you can create a file `/etc/libvirt/hooks/qemu` which determines if your VM is being called, and then does whatever needs to be done.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" = "myvm" ] && [ "$2" = "prepare" ]; then
    /path/to/vfio-pci-bind.sh '0000:03:00.0'
fi
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to know, thanks! I edited the answer so it successfully runs.

Answer (score 0):

@michael-hampton has the most correct answer, but for anyone's reference I was impatient and also made a systemd service called `vfio-pci-bind.service` that executes `vfio-pci-bind.sh`:

```
[Unit]
Description=bind PCI card to vfio

[Service]
ExecStart=/opt/vfio-pci-bind/vfio-pci-bind.sh "0000:03:00.1"
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
```

then I added to `libvirt-guests.service`:

```
[Service]
...
Wants=vfio-pci-bind.service
After=vfio-pci-bind.service
```

The issues with this being

- it relies on systemd rather than being self-contained to libvirt
- it executes vfio-pci-bind regardless of whether or not the affected vm will actually be started at boot

so yeah I'll switch over to libvirt hooks, thanks for the help!